# How to pick Music from the Apple Music App with .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin.ios, maui

I am working with .NET MAUI and I want to pick purchased Music from Apple Music App. Are there any solutions already implemented?

I can't find any similar posts or documentations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If there is one which shows how you do it for Swift or Xam.iOS then you can replicate it here pretty much

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, the [MusicKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/MusicKit/) can implement this function, and there is an [official Sample about using MusicKit in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios11-musickitsample/), you can refer to it. Maui also supports .Net iOS code. You can use conditional compilation or use partial classes and partial methods to call the code of the corresponding platform. For more details, you can refer to [Invoke platform code | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0).

**Note when using MusicKit**: Users must grant permission for your app to access their music data. Add the NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key to your app's Info.plist file, and include a description of how you intend to use the user's media. If this key isn't present, the system terminates your app when it tries to access the user's music.